# Is it possible to replace all carriage returns in a string via .replace?

Tags: javascript, replace

Is it possible to replace all carriage returns in a string with the `.replace` function?  I've found quite a few complex functions to do it, but was wondering if it could be simplified with just a regex through `.replace`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 113):

Both \n (new line) and \r (carraige return) create a new line. To replace all instances of both at the same time:

```
s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
```

Note that you might want to replace them with a single space rather than nothing.

Comment: That damn `/g` always gets me! Who thought it was a good idea to only replace the *first* occurrence by default?

Answer (score 15):

Here how to do it

```
str = str.replace(/\r/gm,'newChar');
```

By default, Javascript `replace()` replaces the first occurance. The way around it is to set the first parameters as a regex.

Comment: I'm using the similar function to replace new lines to <br>'s. But I also add \n and \r\n to regular expression. /\r\n|\r|\n/g

Answer (score 0):

another solution :

```
str = str.replace(RegExp(String.fromCharCode(10), 'g'), 'newChar');
```