# Remove substring in href using Javascript on Kimonlabs

Tags: javascript

How do I remove substring "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" from href example below?

I trying web scrape using Kimonolabs. I am a novice but output has 2 "http://" for some reason

**"href":** "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/healthcare-and-medical-jobs/qualified-flexible-carers/23434",

```js
{
  "name": "DoneDealTitleWexford",
  "count": 20,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 6,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Sun Jun 14 2015 11:40:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/healthcare-and-medical-jobs/qualified-flexible-carers/23434",
          "text": "Qualified Flexible Carer(s)",
          "title": "Qualified Flexible Carer(s)"
        },
        "index": 1,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/motor-mechanic-jobs/apprentice-mechanic/23454",
          "text": "Apprentice Mechanic",
          "title": "Apprentice Mechanic"
        },
        "index": 2,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/sales-jobs/full-time-summer-job-with-a-base-wage-uncapped-commission/24432",
          "text": "Full-time summer job with a base wage + uncapped commission",
          "title": "Full-time summer job with a base wage + uncapped commission"
        },
        "index": 3,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/sales-jobs/residential-sales-team-leader/24431",
          "text": "Residential Sales Team Leader",
          "title": "Residential Sales Team Leader"
        },
        "index": 4,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/pharmaceutical-and-science-jobs/associate-scientist/24506",
          "text": "Associate Scientist",
          "title": "Associate Scientist"
        },
        "index": 5,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/restaurant-and-catering-jobs/restaurant-manager/24505",
          "text": "Restaurant Manager",
          "title": "Restaurant Manager"
        },
        "index": 6,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/pharmaceutical-and-science-jobs/microbiologist-qa-specialist/24504",
          "text": "Microbiologist/ QA Specialist",
          "title": "Microbiologist/ QA Specialist "
        },
        "index": 7,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/pharmaceutical-and-science-jobs/quality-control-analyst-/24500",
          "text": "Quality Control Analyst.",
          "title": "Quality Control Analyst."
        },
        "index": 8,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/accountancy-and-finance-jobs/retail-cash-office-job-in-dublin/24497",
          "text": "Retail Cash Office Job in Dublin",
          "title": "Retail Cash Office Job in Dublin "
        },
        "index": 9,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/project-manager-jobs/project-manager-translation-localisation/24496",
          "text": "Project Manager - Translation / Localisation",
          "title": "Project Manager - Translation / Localisation"
        },
        "index": 10,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/pharmaceutical-and-science-jobs/regulatory-affairs-specialist/24495",
          "text": "Regulatory Affairs Specialist",
          "title": "Regulatory Affairs Specialist "
        },
        "index": 11,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/manufacturing-jobs/sign-makers/24494",
          "text": "Sign Makers",
          "title": "Sign Makers"
        },
        "index": 12,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/hotel-jobs/bakery-supervisor-job-in-cork/24493",
          "text": "Bakery Supervisor Job in Cork",
          "title": "Bakery Supervisor Job in Cork "
        },
        "index": 13,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/hotel-jobs/baker-job-in-cork-city/24492",
          "text": "Baker Job in Cork City",
          "title": "Baker Job in Cork City "
        },
        "index": 14,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/hotel-jobs/duty-manager/24491",
          "text": "Duty Manager",
          "title": "Duty Manager"
        },
        "index": 15,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/accountancy-and-finance-jobs/senior-accounts-assistant-accounting-technician/24489",
          "text": "Senior Accounts Assistant / Accounting Technician",
          "title": "Senior Accounts Assistant / Accounting Technician"
        },
        "index": 16,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/accountancy-and-finance-jobs/accountant-senior-accounting-technician-german-speaking/24488",
          "text": "Accountant / Senior Accounting Technician (German Speaking)",
          "title": "Accountant / Senior Accounting Technician (German Speaking) "
        },
        "index": 17,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/accountancy-and-finance-jobs/credit-controller/24487",
          "text": "Credit Controller",
          "title": "Credit Controller"
        },
        "index": 18,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/accountancy-and-finance-jobs/revenue-analyst/24486",
          "text": "Revenue Analyst",
          "title": "Revenue Analyst"
        },
        "index": 19,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      },
      {
        "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/accountancy-and-finance-jobs/accounts-receivable-team-lead-multiples-retail/24485",
          "text": "Accounts Receivable Team Lead – Multiples / Retail",
          "title": "Accounts Receivable Team Lead – Multiples / Retail"
        },
        "index": 20,
        "url": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/find&county=Wexford&Submit=Search"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: is it always `"http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"` ?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328145/is-it-possible-to-replace-all-carriage-returns-in-a-string-via-replace

Comment: I don't see your code. Are you looking for something like: `newHref = href.substr("http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n".length);` ?

Comment: Hi Medhi yes its always "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

Comment: The code is viewable here https://goo.gl/KviX3a

Comment: Example :  "Title": {
          "href": "http://jobs.donedeal.ie/search/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://jobs.donedeal.ie/view/healthcare-and-medical-jobs/qualified-flexible-carers/23434",
          "text": "Qualified Flexible Carer(s)",
          "title": "Qualified Flexible Carer(s)"
        },