# how to remove carriage return in js

Tags: javascript, split, whitespace, carriage-return

I have set of numbers from an excel like this
05143
05250
05252
05156
05143
05441
05143
05031
05050
05101
05821
05822
05861

and after every 5th digit I wanted to add a `,` 
My problem is that after every 5th digit it considers a white space carriage as a digit and then split the items such as

05143 ↵0525 0↵052 50↵05 and so on...

and that's why `,` split is breaking. I tried to replace it  as `item.replace(/↵/g, "");` but its not working.

here is my code

```
item.replace(/↵/g, "")
                console.log(item)
              if(item.length > 5){
                for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i += 5) {
                       chunks.push(item.substring(i, i + 5));
                   }
                   console.log(chunks)
                    var tempItem;
                     chunks.forEach(function(item2) {
                       if (tempItem == undefined) {
                         tempItem = "'" + item2 + "'";
                       } else {
                         tempItem = tempItem + ",'" + item2 + "'";
                       }
                     })
```

Comment: Isnt it \n ? ...

Comment: Nope.. its not working in that way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to replace all carriage returns in a string via .replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328145/is-it-possible-to-replace-all-carriage-returns-in-a-string-via-replace)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question what character code you have in your string that cause the problem.

But I think that if you use this general replace you will solve.

```
item.replace(/\W/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

it works when we write it as

```
item.split('\n')
```